# PDOException Syntax error or access violation 1142, when creating view referencing other views

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to create a MySQL view within PHP (specifically Laravel) and I'm experiencing a strange error:

```
[PDOException]
SQLSTATE[42000]: SSyntax error or access violation: 1142 ANY command denied to user 'user'@'localhost' for table '/tmp/#sql_475_0'
```

Running the create statements straight in MySQL work correctly. If I remove the joins to the views then everything works. The user has full permissions (GRANT ALL). Extensive Googling hasn't returned anything similar.

My code is below, slightly simplified, with the error being produced when running the 4th statement to create jobs_view.

```
DB::statement("
    CREATE VIEW quote_response_count AS (
        SELECT job_id, COUNT(quotes.id) as total FROM quotes 
        INNER JOIN quote_requests on quote_requests.quote_id = quotes.id 
        INNER JOIN quote_responses on quote_responses.quote_request_id = quote_requests.id
        GROUP BY job_id
    );
");

DB::statement("
    CREATE VIEW customer_paid AS (
        SELECT job_id, SUM(amount) as total FROM transactions 
        WHERE category = 'customer payment' AND is_verified = 1
        GROUP BY job_id, category
    );
");

DB::statement("
    CREATE VIEW company_paid AS (
        SELECT job_id, SUM(amount) as total FROM transactions 
        WHERE category = 'company payment' AND is_verified = 1
        GROUP BY job_id, category
    );
");

DB::statement("
    CREATE VIEW jobs_view AS (
        SELECT 
            jobs.*,         
            IFNULL(customer_paid.total, 0)              AS customer_paid,
            IFNULL(company_paid.total, 0)               AS company_paid,
            IFNULL(quote_response_count.total, 0)       AS responses_received,                  
            price - IFNULL(customer_paid.total, 0)      AS customer_owes,
            cost  - IFNULL(customer_paid.total, 0)      AS owes_company,
            (
                deposit > 0 AND IFNULL(customer_paid.total, 0) >= deposit
            )                                           AS deposit_paid             

         FROM jobs

         LEFT OUTER JOIN quote_response_count   AS quote_response_count ON quote_response_count.job_id  = jobs.id
         LEFT OUTER JOIN customer_paid          AS customer_paid        ON customer_paid.job_id         = jobs.id
         LEFT OUTER JOIN company_paid           AS company_paid         ON company_paid.job_id          = jobs.id
    );
");
```

The output of SHOW GRANTS from within the PHP application are as follows:

```
[Grants for user@localhost] => GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '****************************'

[Grants for user@localhost] => GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `dbname`.* TO 'user'@'localhost'
```

The below very simplified example also produces the same results:

```
DB::statement("
    CREATE TABLE table1 (
        id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        foo varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (id)
    );
");
DB::statement("
    CREATE VIEW view1 AS (
        SELECT id, foo FROM table1
    );
");
DB::statement("
    CREATE VIEW view2 AS (
        SELECT table1.id, view1.foo FROM table1
        INNER JOIN view1 ON view1.id = table1.id
    );
");
```

The same error occurs if just selecting from view1, rather than joining.

The system which I'm experiencing this problem on is a Ubuntu 12.04 server running PHP 5.5.23 and MySQL 5.5.41.

Comment: I see a few attempts at forum posts and bug reports for the same issue, none with a resolution. But they all have `SELECT *` in common. Do you get a different outcome if you list the columns from `jobs` instead of using `jobs.*`?

Comment: In the last statement ('CREATE VIEW jobs_view') you're using the same names for column aliases, tables, and table aliases ('customer_paid', 'company_paid'). Seems like SQL might have a hard time with that... maybe try using a different alias for the tables in the `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

Comment: Also, please show the true output from `SHOW GRANTS` for this user.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski SHOW GRANTS output added to post

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I've removed the * wildcard select and still the same issue

Comment: @luciddreamz I had the same though a few hours ago and changed this to be kinder to SQL, but still the same result. I just tested again, removing the view aliases and also renaming the column aliases, with the same result

Comment: You *did* run `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` after GRANTing them to the user, and you're sure the user itself is correct? Also, try granting the privileges to the user while also specifying the password. I don't think it *should* make any difference in your scenario, but who knows: maybe MySQL thinks differently.

Comment: Yes, the user was added correctly and the privileges FLUSHed. I've also deleted and recreated the user, with no change. I also gave the user access to all objects in all databases, and from any host (`GRANT ALL ON *.* TO user@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '******'`. The create view queries in my question work correctly when running directly in MySQL which leads me to believe PDO is the culprit.

Comment: @RyanVincent Tried executing the three example create queries using PHP's mysqli class, completely bypassing Laravel and PDO. I'm getting exactly the same error code and message when creating the second view.

Comment: That is good  - well, obviously not ;-/ There is something fundamentally 'less than correct' here. ;-/

Comment: Far too incorrect for an Easter Sunday evening...

Comment: Code to create and query the views: [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/gZq9XT8a). I run on PHP 5.3.29 - mysql 5.5.16. I have put the same code [on a website run on a linux box](http://rfv123.eu.pn/testviews/).

Comment: @RyanVincent Just tested this on my server and it works! But why ha ha! I've cloned your PasteBin and changed the SQL commands to be identical to the simplified example in my question: http://pastebin.com/tQ6AwP4r Can you tell me what we're doing differently today for it to suddenly work?

Comment: Hmm... I assume you [switched it off and on again](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nn2FB1P_Mn8) :-) Have you been thinking nice thoughts about the pc today? ;-/ Glad it is working. :)

Comment: The thing never sleeps ha! Do you have any thoughts about why this is now working? I'm thinking I need to look in to which options/attributes Laravel is setting for PDO

Answer (score 3):

Eureka! For anyone else facing this issue, the problem occurs due to Laravel setting the following PDO connection option:

```
PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false
```

Rather than enable Emulate Prepares for my whole application, my solution was to clone my database configuration, override the PDO option, and then use that connection when creating my view:

### config/database.php

```
'mysql' => array(
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => 'localhost',
    'database'  => 'database',
    'username'  => 'user',
    'password'  => 'password',
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
),
'mysql-emulate-prepares' => array(
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => 'localhost',
    'database'  => 'database',
    'username'  => 'user',
    'password'  => 'password',
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
    'options'   => array(
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true,
    ),
),
```

### Migration

```
$rand = rand(10000, 99999);

DB::statement("
    CREATE TABLE table".$rand." (
        id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        foo varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (id)
    );
");
DB::statement("
    CREATE VIEW view".$rand." AS (
        SELECT id, foo FROM table1
    );
");
DB::connection('mysql-emulate-prepares')->statement("
    CREATE VIEW view".($rand+2)." AS (
        SELECT table".$rand.".id, view".$rand.".foo FROM table".$rand."
        INNER JOIN view".$rand." ON view".$rand.".id = table".$rand.".id
    );
");
```

Huge credit to [Ryan Vincent](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3184785/ryan-vincent) for helping me debug this.

Comment: Hey, you’re the best!! I decided to use an environment variable to (un)set the option, since I don’t mind having it set for all migrations. In my _database.php_ I have `'options' => [PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => env('DB_ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES', false)]` and I run migrations with `DB_ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES=true php artisan migrate`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution which does not involve creating and specifying a separate configuration:

```
$dconn = DB::connection()->getDoctrineConnection();
$dconn->exec("CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW ...");
```

Be aware:

Calling `getDoctrineConnection()` method creates a **new PDO object** that is not tracked by the `DatabaseManager`.

This means that `DB::reconnect()`, `DB::disconnect()`, or `DB::purge()` will not affect this new PDO object. Thus, it will remain as an open connection for the remainder of the request.

This is usually not a problem in a web request or deployment operation as the script eventually ends. However, if one is using a long running demonized PHP process with something like Gearman or Resque then eventually a PDO exception will be thrown with the message `MySQL server has gone away (error 2006)`

The solution to this problem is to explicitly close the Doctrine connection like so:

```
$dconn = DB::connection()->getDoctrineConnection();
$dconn->exec("CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW ...");
$dconn->close();
```